# Is it possible to add an ArcMap map to a report in Access?

Tags: mxd, ms-access

I am using Access to create printable maps where I can change parameters (border colors) on the fly...

Currently, I am exporting the maps to JPEG then pulling them in.  I would like to import MXD files so I can easily modify either the maps or frames on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

With arcengine you can put a mapcontrol in an access form, and an mxd can be used to specificy layers and symbology  I don't think you can put one in a report.